# Returning object model to a view, that is handled by different controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, object, model, master-pages

how can I pass an object model to a view, that is partial view on a master page?

regards

Comment: two things would help. 1) a clearer question, and 2) some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating an another object that more closely represents the view you are trying to render.

Let's say i have an `MyDomain.Order` object, so I make a view page that looks something like `ViewPage<MyDomain.Order>`. Now, let's say that I have a menu that is driven off of a logged in user, as example. It wouldn't make sense to have menu as a property of `MyDomain.Order`. I would create another object, specifically for the view, call it something like `OrderPageModel` and have `MyDomain.Order` and `List<MenuItem>` as properties of this new object, my view being set up as `ViewPage<OrderPageModel>`.

The other thing to consider might be something like `Html.RenderAction()`. Same scenario, I have a view, and as you mention in your question, it has a master page, and as in my example, lets say it hosts a menu common to your site. You could create a partial view (`UserMenu.ascx`) and a controller (`SiteController.cs`) with an action (`UserMenu`) that calculates the items for the menu. Inside your master page, you can then call `<% Html.RenderAction("UserMenu","SiteController") %>`.

I would use the first example if it could be something made for a particular view: just make it a part of the model. I would use the second example if it was something more generic to the site, like a menu.

Comment: In my case, I have LogIn.ascx partial view on my MasterPage. I then process user validation in AccountController and then I would like to pass some data (object model) back to that Login.ascx to show username, etc.

Comment: And you are not going with the concept of a link on the master page to the login page? Are you using an Ajax-style login?

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the location of the view:

```
return PartialView("~/Views/SomeOtherController/SomePartial.ascx", someModel);
```

Answer (score 0):

Best bet here is RenderAction over RenderPartial. Your child controller can easily figure out if the user is logged in and render the right partial rather than making your master page worry about these details.